Solving ODE, why Mathematica gives more complicated results than Maple?
I don't know why this question was closed. The notice indicates this is due to "simple mistake" or something that could be easily found in documentation. I don't think the question falls into either of the two categories. My initial post has an error in code but I immediately revised.
sol = FullSimplify[ DSolve[{s'[t] == \[Beta] + \[Lambda][t] - \[Delta] s[t], \[Lambda]'[t] == \[Gamma] s[t] + ( \[Gamma] + r) \[Lambda][t]}, {s[t], \[Lambda][t]}, t] ] ;
expr = TrigToExp[sol]; 
expr
LeafCount[expr]

Output is very complicated

Maple code:
sol := dsolve([diff(l(t), t) = gamma*s(t) + (gamma + r)*l(t), diff(s(t), t) = beta + l(t) - delta*s(t)], [l(t), s(t)])

simplify(sol[1])
simplify(sol[2])


The expressions in the Maple results are very "nice": each is the sum of three parts: a constant, c1 times Exp(a negative value times t), c2 times Exp(a positive value times t).

Is there a way to let Mathematica output something similar?

The ODE in Maple is not equivalent to the ODE in Mathematica. It should be sol := dsolve([diff(l(t), t) = gamma*s(t) + (gamma + r)*l(t), diff(s(t), t) = beta + l(t) - delta*s(t)], [l(t), s(t)]) in Maple (the multiplication signs instead of substruction signs). In this case the big Maple result is equivalent to the Mathematica's one.

My code in Maple was correct. But when I copied the code from pdf (generated by Maple and then converted to word) and pasted to here, dot was changed to -. Of course the two results are very different in terms of simplicity.

FYI, the default constants of integration are C[1] and C[2] and not c[1] and c[2]

Too large for comment

Of course the two results are very different in terms of simplicity

After simplifying both results, Mathematica's leaf count is 262, while Maple's is 269.
ps. you can use lambda in Maple, using l for the dependent variable is not a good choice as it looks like 1 on the screen.
restart;
sol := dsolve([diff(lambda(t), t) = gamma*s(t) + (gamma + r)*lambda(t), diff(s(t), t) = beta + lambda(t) - delta*s(t)]):
sol:=simplify(sol);
MmaTranslator:-Mma:-LeafCount(sol);


In Mathematica:
sol = DSolve[{s'[t] == β + λ[t] - δ s[t], λ'[t] == γ s[t] + (γ + r) λ[t]}, 
     {s[t], λ[t]}, t];
sol = FullSimplify[%]


LeafCount[sol]
(* 262 *)

Solutions also look similar by looking at them. Maple uses exponential for $s(t)$ and Mathematica used hyperbolic trig functions instead.

In optimal control models in Economics, Exp is popular but I haven't seen Sinh nor Cosh. If you change the Mathematica solution to Exp, the leaf count is over 315.
